# SQL query, distinct rows needed

Tags: sql, ms-access, distinct

I have the following table structured like this:

[image: row structure]

So basically as you can see, the department goes through name changes every couple of years. Look at number 16 for example. I want a select query that will only get the name when the date is the greatest. How do I do that?

Comment: Access table, using access 2007

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select ID, Name from departments o 
where o.thedate=
  (select max(i.thedate) from departments i where o.id=i.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, 
First(Name) AS FirstOfName, First(DateChange) AS FirstOfDateChange
FROM departments
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY First(DateChange) DESC;
```

Comment: +1 for Alt. Solution. The group by ID threw me, but in this case, it is the duplicate data field.

Answer (score 0):

What is the primary key for this table? This does a subquery the same table with a name comparison.

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    date
FROM table
WHERE name = (SELECT TOP 1 name
              FROM table AS subtable
              WHERE subtable.name = table.name
              ORDER BY date DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT d.*
FROM Departments d
INNER JOIN (SELECT pk 
            FROM Departments 
            GROUP BY ID 
            HAVING theDate=MAX(theDate)) m ON m.pk=d.pk
WHERE [Name]="Department"